# liquibase-maven-plugin and sqlFile

Tags: maven, liquibase

I'm trying to use liquibase-maven-plugin to run my database update.  I have the following plugin configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <username>${dba.username}</username>
    <password>${dba.password}</password>
    <url>${caesium.url}</url>
    <changeLogFile>master.xml</changeLogFile>
    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
    <includeArtifact>true</includeArtifact>
</configuration>
```

I keep my database changelogs (and SQL) files in src/main/resources.  My changesets are as follow:

master.xml:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
    <include file="baseline.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

baseline.xml:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet id="base-roles" author="asdf" dbms="PostgreSQL">
        <sqlFile path="sql/some-file.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The some-file.sql is, as specified in sql subdirectory of resources (so, relative to the changelog, it *is* sql/some-file.sql).

Alas!  The above construct doesn't work!  The sql file cannot be found by liquibase.

Strangely enough, when I set the main script to absolute path, everything works OK.  However, that's NOT what I want to do (I don't want to have absolute path in the databasechangelog table).

Comment: Oh... I think I know what the problem is: liquibase is incapapble of figuring out the 'base' directory if the main script isn't in a subdirectory.  Moving everything one step deeper (so that my master.xml is foo/master.xml), fixes the problem.

Comment: You can make use of `${project.basedir}` then to avoid hard-coding the name of the project.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how you managed to fix it, Do 'master.xml' and 'baseline.xml' reside in the same directory? How about 'sql' folder's location? Can you give provide the directory structure? Thanks

Comment: I din't want to use project.basedir, because doing this would make the filenames in the databasechangelog absolute.  You don't want to do it, because if you run your maven build from a different directory, liquibase will think that it's a different change.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going answer my own question in case someone else has similar problem (from the comment, I can see that someone bumped into this).

The problem is this: I pointed to my main script (the change file) as: `<changeLogFile>master.xml</changeLogFile>`.  Liquibase found it on classpath, but, for some reason, couldn't figure out in which directory it is (I think this is simply a bug).

My structure (one that didn't work) was like this:

`src/main/resources
  master.xml
  baseline.xml
  sql
    somefile.sql`

Everything had `relativeToChangelogFile="true"`, so if liquibase found `master.xml`, it should be able to find everything else.  The workaround is to place everything in a sub-directory.  Something like this will do:

`src/main/resources
  liquibase-bug-workaround
    master.xml
    baseline.xml
    sql
      somefile.sql`

... and change the plugin configuration to `<changeLogFile>liquibase-bug-workaround/master.xml</changeLogFile>`.  No other changes required, everything works as it should.